Rust ioctl() analog to ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY);
I am new in rust and trying to rewrite example of https://kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/input/uinput.html in rust using nix crate. But at already first ioctl() in C I have problem to find analog macro in nix::ioctl. I mean this one:
ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY);

What could be a solution for this one?

The nix crate doesn't allow you to call ioctl directly. Instead it offers macros to create wrappers around ioctl calls, then you can call these wrappers.
UI_SET_EVBIT is defined in linux/uinput.h as:
#define UINPUT_IOCTL_BASE    'U'
#define UI_SET_EVBIT                _IOW(UINPUT_IOCTL_BASE, 100, int)

which translate as:
const UINPUT_IOCTL_BASE: u8 = b'U'; // Defined in linux/uinput.h
ioctl_write_int!(ui_set_evbit, UINPUT_IOCTL_BASE, 100);

and you can now call the ui_set_evbit function like this:
const EV_KEY: nix::sys::ioctl::ioctl_param_type = 1; // Defined in linux/input-event-codes.h
unsafe ui_set_evbit (EV_KEY).unwrap();

